# A collider is better to be static when checking collision?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So... As far as I know it's only good practice to make any GameObject Static if that object is not meant to move, therefore I also thought even a rolling stone with a rigidbody shouldn't be a static GameObject.

However, I was commented by someone as a 'Unity Tip FYI' the physics calculation spikes up when an object checks collision whilst it's rotating, so to make the collider static for the sake of better performance(even meer small amount).

I'm really not getting this idea.
Does this make any sense to anyone here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what that comment is saying. It doesn't make sense. Also, it looks like you are confusing static collider and marking GameObject as static.

- Marking Object as static from the Editor

  Telling Unity to batch it. It is used to increase rendering performance. (This has nothing to do with colliders)
- Static Collider

  Telling Unity that the Rigidbody will not be moved.

From your question, you are describing Static Collider. *Static Collider work for both 3D and 2D physics system*.

**What is a Static Collider:**

Static Collider is when you have a GameObject with any type of collider but **no** Rigidbody attached to it.

**How to create a Static Collider:**
To make a GameObject a Static Collider on, attach a collider to that GameObject but **don't** attach `Rigidbody` to it. It is now a Static Collider.

To make it non Static Collider, attach Rigidbody to it.

**What it is used for:**

When you have **many** Objects that you want your collide with but you are 100 percent sure that this Object will not be moved by you or player.

One good example is a brick wall. You simply want the wall to stop the player but you don't want to move the wall. It could also be used for stones in an environment to prevent player collison. Imagine having to attach hundreds or thousands of Rigidbodies to each stone Object with a collider.

It is used to increase physics performance.

**What happens when you move a Static Collider**:

Don't. When GameObject is made to be Static Collider, it is expected that you never move it. If you do, it will spike cause spike in CPU. This introduces constant freezing in your game each time you try to move it. This spike has been reduced in *Unity 5* but it is still there. I think that's what that comment is trying to say. This whole thing happens because it has to recalculate the physical world all over again. From Unity's website, below is a screenshot of what happens when you try to move a Static Collider Object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation with examples! What I was doing was having numerous GameObjects as ‘interactable props’ in the scene. Before the ‘commentator’ gave this not so fully explained tip I was setting this type of GameObject attaching graphic element + collider + rigidbody all in one GameObject. Since this type of GameObject needed to be moved and even roll by gameplay time to time I think this was why the moment the commentator jumped in. I was told to ‘check the static’ of the ‘collider’ object and never rotate it, but I think he was trying to explain what you are, but not exactly.

Comment: If the GameObject has Collider attached to it and you are or want move it, you must attach `Rigidbody` to it other expect unexpected spikes which will be very noticeable on mobile devices. That's all you need to know.

Comment: So, this type of ‘Interactable // mobile GameObject’ needs to be set up with both collider && rigidbody on one GameObject, and what the ‘tip’ wanted me to notice was the ‘GameObject with static collider(no rigidbody)’ to prevent this spike of CPU load, correct?

Comment: Not exactly. He wanted you to know that if you want to move that object that has a collider, you must also attach Rigidbody to it to prevent CPU spike. If you are not moving it, you don't need Rigidbody. If you are moving it but don't need the object to collide with anything then remove both the collider and Rigidbody since you don't need them .

Comment: Again, much appreciated for clarifying my confusion. At this point I’m not even sure why he wanted me to know this(though, the tip itself was totally viable accept to ‘check the static checkbox’ to do it) when I was moving a GameObject with collider + rigidbody. Was my example of parenting hierarchy is not really the issue, was it?

Comment: *"Was my example of parenting hierarchy is not really the issue, was it?"* It could be. I forgot to mention this but there is a bug in Unity that Unity recommends that you do not move a child Object with a `Rigidbody`. This is a long ago and I am not sure if that has been fixed. It is recommended to move the parent object not the child with the Rigidbody.  What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: In fact, I did not have any problem both in performance and behavior with this ‘interactable props.’ The commentator just jumped out and gave me a heads-up of this tip which I really needed to clarify since his explanation was not solid enough for such a crucial outcome if gone wrong. I’m working with 5.6 and I’ve not yet found such dramatic CPU load spikes while attempting to move the gameObjects. If my parenting hierarchy could be improved I’d fix them, but they haven’t cause any of these dramatic spikes caused by attempting to move static colliders which all had rigidbody with them, so...

Comment: *"haven’t cause any of these dramatic spikes caused by attempting to move static colliders which all had rigidbody with them"* That's because they have rigidbody attached to them, so they are not static collider. It is only static collider when there is no rigidbody and then it will cause spike like I mentioned in my answer. The advice you got from that person is good since some people don't know about this

Comment: I admit this was something I should be aware of in order to prevent possible setup mistakes aside from my current setups. I do think I should tell him checking the static box is not what he wants to do to care about this, though. Still wonder why he connected this tip with rigidbody, though: The main confusion source off of this initial topic.

Comment: rigidbody matters in this. Since the presence of rigidbody is what decides if should be a static collider or dynamic collider. what doesn't matter is the "checking the static box". You should tell him that.

Answer (score 1):

A static game object is not the same as a static rigidbody/collider, they're two completely different concept.

Static game objects are used to save performance time/memory regarding rendering, navigation meshes, etc., you can read about them here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html

Static colliders are a totally different beast. A static collider is used to tell Unity that this object will never move under any circumstance, so it will save quite some calculations in the physics engine.

Finally, regarding the tip that you mentioned: I think that probably the author of that tip was talking about 3D colliders, and by "static" he meant that you should separate the 3D mesh from the 3D collider, so when the mesh must be rotated, you rotate only that and not the collider.

Think of a sphere, you create a parent game object, then two children: one that has the Mesh component, and the other the Sphere collider. When you want to rotate the sphere in place, you only rotate the mesh child and not the collider, and when you want to translate instead the sphere, you just translate the parent game object in order to change the position of both children.

Comment: Wow, this is mind-blowing. So in my project that’s basically a 3D environment what I should do with my objects such as an intractable physically behaving pebble: Rigidbody parent GO + graphics element child GO + static collider child GO, right? Then when the pebble should roll down slope in physical manner I should only rotate the graphics child GO. Have I got this right? From your great summary it WAS faulty to say: check static on that static collider since the whole group of this type of GameObject is not ‘a static gameobject.’ Correct?

Comment: Static collider don't only exist for  2D physics engine. It exist for both 3D and 2D and in-fact, was even implemented for 3D years before  2D supported was added. And calculation spikes is not about separating mesh and colliders

Comment: Edited to correct the wrong statement about static colliders only existing in 2D, check Programmer answer about that.